# Unboxing an untyped field in a DataRow Without a Casting Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, unboxing

The data layer of my ASP.Net app calls a stored proc to get a small (one record) amount of information about a visitor upon login.  I pass in their phone number and the sproc, using a simple SELECT, passes back 5 fields, the first of which is the primary key, a BIGINT.  My data layer gets the DataRow and tries to create a data object with it.  In the data object, the property that represents the primary key is an Int64.  That looks like this:

```
 sub = new PersistentSubscriber((String) dr["UserFirstName"],
        (String) dr["UserLastName"],
        phoneNumber, (Int64) dr["UserId"], (Byte) dr["SubscriberStatus"]);
```

What I'm finding is that everything works great when I have a big primary key value, such as 88698.  However, when I get a small one, like 999, I get a "Specified Cast is Invalid" error when trying to set up that primary key property.  When I try playing with it in the Immediate window, I get this:

```
?(Int64)dr["UserId"]
Cannot unbox 'dr["UserId"]' as a 'long'
?(int)dr["UserId"]
999
?(Int32)dr["UserId"]
999
```

Without resorting to a typed dataset, what am I doing wrong, here?

Comment: As far as conversion calls like Convert and TryParse go, I suppose that will work, but I'm more concerned with "WHY" do I need to do that at all?  999 is a valid Int32 just as it is a valid Int64.  Why should I have to do any conversion whatsoever?  If I know it won't ever be bigger than the type can handle, I should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Granted I'm digging up an old question, but it showed up for me in a google search near the top so why not...

Have you heard of [DataSetExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155261.aspx)? They let you access fields in a DataRow in a strongly-typed way. This is extremely useful in linq queries, and in my experience can be significantly faster than calling DataTable.Select().

Just add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` to your project, and you're ready use them.

In Example:

```
Int64 value = dr.Field<Int64>("UserId");

dr.SetField("UserId", value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving `Int64.TryParse` a shot.

```
long userId;
if(Int64.TryParse(dr["UserId"], out userId))
{
    // successful conversion
}
```